# How to get left margin of an image as ems in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I searched this over internet for over 3 hours and none of the suggestions work in my code. What i am trying to do is to slide pictures to left one by one in each click (total 3 pictures) and when the last picture is in the screen stop sliding left and slide back to the first picture. To do that I need to detect the left margin of the first picture when it hits a certain spot (180em to the left) and compare it to an "ems" value (code is below). The "if" statement never shoots, it always directs to "else".

I tried to get the left border position (or margin) of the first picture with "$('#picture1').offsetLeft", "$('#picture1').layerX", "$('#picture1').left" too but none of them worked.

If you can direct me to another website, another question in Stackoverflow or give me a solution I will appreciate it.

Note: I am very very new with javascript, if there are mistakes in my code or my question correct me. Thank you.

```
var position = parseInt(jQuery("#picture1").css("margin-left"));
var left_border = '180ems';
    $(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {
            if (position > 180ems) {
               $("#picture1").animate({
                   left: '-=60em'
               }, 600);
               $("#picture2").animate({
                   left: '-=60em'
               }, 600);
               $("#picture3").animate({
                   left: '-=60em'
               }, 600);
            }
            else {
                $("#picture1").animate({
                   left: '+=180em'
               }, 600);
               $("picture2").animate({
                   left: '+=120em'
               }, 600);
               $("#picture3").animate({
                   left: '+=60em'
               }, 600);
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always get the value in pixels and then try to convert this to ems, see this question [jQuery/JavaScript: convert pixels to em in a easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305993/jquery-javascript-convert-pixels-to-em-in-a-easy-way)

Edit: Or you could place an invisible element 180ems from the left, and then fetch the pixel value for this from that element, you can then use that value for comparison.

Comment: I will try both of these tomorrow and let you know. I liked the second idea better, I will probably use it many other things. Thank you very much!

Comment: So I ended up using '.position().left' to determine position as an integer and converting it into ems by detecting browser's font size. Thanks for the suggestion.