# jQuery, set element width minus size in em

Tags: jquery, width

I want to apply the width of `#div_A` minus 3 **em** to `#div_B`.

`$("#div_B").width($("#div_A").width() - 3);`

I did not find anything that explained how to specify only *3* in em.

Thanks!

Comment: first of all, you are assigning the width of div_b to div_a, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305993/jquery-javascript-convert-pixels-to-em-in-a-easy-way) is how to convert pixels to em using jquery.

you could however, take advantage of the css [calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) function in combination with jquery to make it much much shorter:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#div_B").css({
    "width": "calc(" + $("#div_A").width() + "px - 3em)"
  });
});
```

```css
div{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
#div_A{
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_A"></div>
<div id="div_B"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this calc function. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

For full browser support you have to figure out how much `3em` is in pixels.

You'd do that by using an element set to `3em` and getting the pixel value from it

```
var div = $('<div />', {
    css : {
        position : 'relative',
        width    : '3em',
        height   : '1em'
    }
}).appendTo('body');

var w = div.width(); // width of 3em in pixels

div.remove();

$("#div_B").width( $("#div_A").width() - w );
```

As `em` is the same as the currently used font-size, one could also do

```
var em = (+$("#div_A").css('font-size').replace(/\D/g,''));
$("#div_B").width( $("#div_A").width() - (em * 3) );
```

Comment: That's a good solution too, thanks. In my case there's a limit to it as the em size of an element is relative to the em size of its parent element.
So I would have to make the `var div` I use to calculate 3em appendTo the element in which `#div_B` is located.

Comment: `.appendTo($('#div_B').parent())`

Comment: Actually, `em` would be relative to the font-size, so you really just need to get the font-size and divide by 3