# How to guarantee an element will have a particular height

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

Say that I have this element on my page:

```
<div style="height: 1em;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I want to use JavaScript to measure the height of the `div` to figure out how many px are equivalent to 1em for that element.

So if I did:

```
document.querySelector('div').getBoundingClientRect()
```

Then I might get `16`.

But what if users can inject arbitrary styles onto this webpage?  What if they do something like:

```
div { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Then I would get `18`, because of the unexpected border applied to all `div` elements.

To avoid this, I could add a laundry list of styles to the div to remove potential "unexpected styles:"

```
<div style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 1em;">&nbsp;</div>
```

But is that list of styles comprehensive?  If not, what other styles do I need?  Or is there a better way to make this calculation?

Comment: You can try substracting the 2 times the width of that div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `font-style: 1em !important;` on the element, and get the font size in `px` using [Window#getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(div).fontSize;

console.log(fontSize);
```

```html
<div id="div" style="font-size: 1em;"></div>
```

**My previous not bullet proof answer:**

*This fails if the user uses borders and/or paddings which height is greater than 16.*

You can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on the element. With this box sizing, the borders and the paddings don't increase the dimensions of the element. The content area is the original width/height **minus** any paddings and borders.

```js
console.log(div.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="height: 1em; box-sizing: border-box;">
```

Comment: It's very convenient that `fontSize` is a decimal px value!  Worked for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and IE11.